# Wild card searches using a list of values in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a search against a field on a table, which can contain a combination of all sorts of string values such as single words or complete sentences.

What I trying to do is to create a query that searches on this field and returns any rows that contains any of the words and combination of words from a list as my predicate parameter.

Is there a way of passing in this list as a wild card search?

Comment: Show us what this list looks like

Comment: Probably what you want is [Oracle Text, the built-in free searching capability](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCAPP/toc.htm).

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you have a list of keywords, and you need to filter all those rows for which a certain column contains one or more keywords.

Two possible ways that I can think of  -

1. using REGEXP_LIKE

   select * from tbl where regexp_like(col, '^(ABC|EFG|IJK)');
2. Maintaining the list of keywords in a separate table and join the tables -

   CREATE TABLE matching_patterns(
   pattern VARCHAR(20)
   );

   ```
    INSERT INTO patterns VALUES ('%ABC%'), ('%EFG%'), ('%IJK%');

    SELECT t.* FROM your_table t JOIN matching_patternsp ON (t.your_column LIKE p.pattern);
   ```

Comment: Almost, but ti give an example of the words I searching for are bit like, 'cat, dog, the dog ran, the cat ran, man, woman'. The list will by like that